# Python Won't Run

Tags: python

My python program prints the first thing I wrote, and then loads forever and never prints the second task. What do I need to change with my code?

import random

def main():

```
money = 100

win = 0
loss = 0
draw = 0

bet = random.randint(5, 20)

print('You are starting with $100 and each round you will bet', bet, 'dollors')

while True:
  
    x = random.randint(1, 6)
    y = random.randint(1, 6)
    z = x + y
    
    if money == 0 or money == 200:
        break     

    if z == 7 or z == 11:
        money += bet
        win += 1
        
    elif z == 2 or z == 3 or z == 12:
        loss += 1
        money -= bet 

    else: 
        draw += 1
    
    
print('You ended up with', money, 'dollars, and you won', win, 'rounds, lost', \
      loss, 'rounds, and drew', draw, 'rounds')
```

main()

Comment: I just realized that it will only load forever and not print when the money ends up equaling 0. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: change your if condition statements and loop terminations perfectly it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will never be able to satisfy all the conditions and is caught in a infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use correct condition in the if condition and i suggest u to use a var to run the loop and to break the loop.

```
import random

def main():

money = 100

win = 0
loss = 0
draw = 0

bet = random.randint(5, 20)

print('You are starting with $100 and each round you will bet', bet, 'dollors')


loop  = True

while loop:

     x = random.randint(1, 6)
     y = random.randint(1, 6)
     z = x + y

    if money <= 0 or money >= 200:
       loop = False

    if z == 7 or z == 11:
       money += bet
       win += 1
    
    elif z == 2 or z == 3 or z == 12:
       loss += 1
       money -= bet 

    else: 
       draw += 1


print('You ended up with', money, 'dollars, and you won', win, 'rounds, lost', \
  loss, 'rounds, and drew', draw, 'rounds')
```